# Elasticsearch discard documents that contain superset of query

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have 3 documents:

```
{ "cities": "Paris Zurich Milan" }
{ "cities": "Paris Zurich" }
{ "cities": "Zurich"}
```

`cities` is just text, I'm not using any custom analyzer.
I want to query for documents that have in `cities` both Paris and Zurich, in this order, and do not have any other city. So I want to get only the second document.

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "cities": "Paris Zurich"
        }
     }
}
```

But this returns also the first document.
What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about case sensitivity just use `term` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cities.keyword": "Paris Zurich"
    }
  }
}
```

It will only match the exact value of field.

On the other hand you can create custom analyzer that will still store the exact value of field (just like `keyword`) with one exception: the stored value will be converted to lowercase so you will be able to find `Paris Zurich` as well as `paris Zurich`. Here is the example:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "cities": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "lowercased": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cities.lowercased": "paris zurich" // Query string should also be in lowercase
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually care about case sensitivity so using .keyword is perfect. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A question I have is, how did I miss this? I saw the term query, but in the documentation they don't mention the .keyword thing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html